# Cart in Android Using Static Class

Tags: android

Hello I am new to android, currently I am trying to build a cart in my application using a static class:

```
package com.xxxxxx.vendor.helpers;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

    public class Cart {

        public static JSONObject Info;
        public static JSONObject Customer;
        public static JSONArray Tickets;
        public static JSONArray Extras;

    }
```

Now I have a button that is supposed to add a jsonObject to my Tickets JSONArray on button click:

```
 btView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            int qty = Integer.parseInt(tqView.getText().toString());
                            String tClass = ticketsArr.getJSONObject(finalI).get("class").toString();
                            String eName = eo.getName();

                            JSONObject t = new JSONObject();
                            t.put("id", ticketsArr.getJSONObject(finalI).get("id").toString());
                            t.put("class", tClass);

                            String description = tClass + " ticket" + (qty > 1 ? "s" : "") + " to" + eName;
                            t.put("description", description);

                            t.put("price", ticketsArr.getJSONObject(finalI).get("fee").toString());
                            t.put("quantity", qty);

                            // Cart.Tickets.put(t);

                            JSONArray tArr = Cart.Tickets;
                            tArr.put(t);

                            Toast.makeText(TicketsActivity.this, Cart.Tickets.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                })
```

However whenever I click the button the app crashes at this line: `tArr.put(t);`
I have no idea what I am doing wrong here, although my object oriented is a bit rusty so I may be making a silly mistake somewhere.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to consider using custom objects that you serialize and deserialize using a library such as GSON. It'll make everything much easier as you won't have to worry about try and catch blocks and checking if a field is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `Cart.Tickets` is null . You have not added anything  to`Cart.Tickets`
and hence `tArr` is `null`

```
  JSONArray tArr = Cart.Tickets;
```

You need to assign some value to `Cart.Tickets` before using it in order to avoid any crashes.

Comment: Ahhh thanks was thinking I didn't need to do that because it was a static JSONArray.

Comment: Any object static or non-static should be initialized before using it.